# function for validation input c++ simple

Tags: c++

to some this might seem simple, but to me I can't really seem to figure out why this isn't working. I know I could just copy and paste every time inside the while loop to get the result I want, but I've been told that if you have to repeat something more than one time to write a function! My code will double print the number and even though someone would type 8 it will still go into the while loop. Hoping someone can explain why this is happening to me.

```
int main()
{
int option = selectionHelper();
cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
cout << endl;
if(option == 8)
{
    cout << "Exiting program..." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;
}
while (option != 8)
{
if (option == 1){

    cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;
}else if(option == 2){

    cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;
}else if(option == 3){

    cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;
}else if(option == 4){

    cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;
}else if(option == 5){

    cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;
}else if(option == 6){

    cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;
}else if(option == 7){

    cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;
}else{
    cout << "Invalid input... Please try again..." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;
}//end else if statement
}//end while loop

}//end function main
```

and now for my function:

```
int selectionHelper()
{
int option;
cout << "1.  Initialize seating for new performance." << endl;
cout << "2.  View seating chart." << endl;
cout << "3.  Reserve seats." << endl;
cout << "4.  Calculate tickets remaining in row." << endl;
cout << "5.  Calculate tickets remaining in theater." << endl;
cout << "6.  Calculate total tickets sold." << endl;
cout << "7.  Calculate ticket sales." << endl;
cout << "8.  Exit program." << endl;
cout << "Option: " << endl;
cin >> option;
return option;
}//end selectionHelper
```

Thank you for looking at my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer and others will tell you what code to write to fix your problem. If you should encounter similar problems in the future, try walking through your code with a debugger. (Experience helps too.) Regarding code redundancy: first, it's good that you used the selectionHelper() method. That shows you have good instincts. Here's what you can do further:

1. Look for lines of code that are the same or differ only by a variable.
2. Consider condensing them in the following ways:

   - Can you use a for-loop?
   - Can you put the code in a method (possibly abstracting out a variable?)
   - Can you use a broader conditional statement? (That's what you have going on here: if a number is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7, it's also >0 and <7. That's why we have ranges.)

The program keeps going when they enter 8 because you ask them to input a number after they input 8! So your first chunk of code can be simpler:

```
int option = selectionHelper();
cout << option << endl <<endl; // <-- output option, don't call selectionHelper() here again, that's why you get double printing
if(option == 8)
{
    cout << "Exiting program..." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    //cin >> option; // <-- don't input here again!
}
```

The key here to simplifying your code is to recognize that you only write different code in a few cases. So, here's your `while` loop:

```
while (option != 8)
{
    if (option > 0 && option < 8){

        cout << selectionHelper() << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cin >> option;
    }else{
        cout << "Invalid input... Please try again..." << ends << endl;
       cout << selectionHelper() << endl << endl;
       cin >> option;
    }//end else if statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must modify your code in the following ways:

```
int option = selectionHelper();
cout << option << endl;
```

And also:

```
if(option == 8)
{
    cout << "Exiting program..." << endl;
}
```

You can simplify your code down to (using partly the simplification made by [cuniculus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5478284/cuniculus) but also fixing the mistake in your own code of wrong using `option`):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int selectionHelper()
{
int option;
cout << "1.  Initialize seating for new performance." << endl;
cout << "2.  View seating chart." << endl;
cout << "3.  Reserve seats." << endl;
cout << "4.  Calculate tickets remaining in row." << endl;
cout << "5.  Calculate tickets remaining in theater." << endl;
cout << "6.  Calculate total tickets sold." << endl;
cout << "7.  Calculate ticket sales." << endl;
cout << "8.  Exit program." << endl;
cout << "Option: " << endl;
cin >> option;
return option;
}//end selectionHelper

int main()
{
int option = selectionHelper();
while (option != 8)
{
    if (option > 0 && option < 8){
        option = selectionHelper();
    }else{
        cout << "Invalid input... Please try again..." << ends << endl;
       option = selectionHelper();
    }//end else if statement
}
cout << "Exiting program..." << endl;
return 0;
}//end function main
```

Your mistake was basically in calling `selectionHelper` too many times, when only once is needed to set the `option` variable. You have a similar thing going on in your whole if-else structure - but I'll leave it up to you to fix that if needed, the solution is the same.

Comment: This also helped me see which part of the code was causing the error. Thank you for replying to my post!

Comment: Great. Please upvote those answers which you find useful (click the uparrow to the left of the answer).